# Using * logic in mandatory prompt

Tags: business-objects

I have created one mandatory prompt @report level then tried to convert into optional prompt by using below logic.

```
Agg_yr_qt_mt_mn_wk_rg_cy_sn_sr_qt_ma.Yr  =  @prompt('Enter Year: or  (* for all): ',
'A','Time period\Year',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0) or '*' In @prompt(
'Enter Year: or  (* for all) :','A','Time period\Year',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0))
```

But the prompts are showing two times.

PS: I have used e-fashion universe for testing '*' logic.

Please advice.

-Sachin

Answer (score 0):

The prompt strings need to match **exactly**.  You are missing the "*" in the second one, and the colon is misplaced.  Try:

```
Agg_yr_qt_mt_mn_wk_rg_cy_sn_sr_qt_ma.Yr = 
@prompt('Enter Year: or (* for all): ','A','Time period\Year',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0) or '' In 
@prompt('Enter Year: or (* for all): ','A','Time period\Year',Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:0))
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for the reply but that was my typo mistake. I am using the same string in both @prompt.

Comment: Well, the missing asterisks are probably because of SO formatting, but are you certain that the colon at the end is in the same place?  Also, if you're on XI3.1 or above, you can set a report-level prompt as optional.